# How do I get the row number of the cell where the UITextView was edited?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

- I have a **UITextView** inside each cell of a **UITableView**
- I am using **Core Data** to save data which is typed in the UITextView
- I would like to save the text typed in UITextView once the user is done editing it
- I have added **UITextViewDelegate** to my *TableViewCell* class
- I am using **Notifications** to post the new text to the *TableViewController*

> I am able to get the new text to the *TableViewController* but I don't know how to get the row number of the cell that contained the textview wherein the text was typed. I need to know the row number (or the object in that row) to update the correct NSManagedObject.

What I have Tried:

- I was thinking about using tags but since I need to constantly add and delete rows it wouldn't be the best approach
- I have tried using **DidSelectedRowAtIndexPath** but it doesn't get triggered while the
  user taps the UITextView (UITextView covers up to 80% of the one cell)

In the TableViewCell class, I have:

```
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    // Post notification

    let userInfo = [ "text" : textView.text]

    NotificationCenter.default.post(
    name: UITextView.textDidEndEditingNotification, 
    object: nil, 
    userInfo: userInfo as [AnyHashable : Any])
}
```

In the TableViewController, I have:

```
    //Subscribe
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
    selector: #selector(textEditingEnded(notification:)),
    name: UITextView.textDidEndEditingNotification, 
    object: nil)


    @objc func textEditingEnded(notification:Notification) {

        guard let text = notification.userInfo?["text"] as? String else {return}
        print ("text: \(text)")   
    }
```

Don't hesitate to ask for more details.
I'll appreciate every bit of help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a property of the `NSManagedObject` type in the table view cell.
- In Interface Builder connect the `delegate` of the text view to the cell.
- In the controller pass the appropriate data source item in `cellForRowAt` to the cell.
- Delete the observer and instead of posting a notification change the attribute in the `NSManagedObject` instance directly and save the context.

As `NSManagedObject` instances are reference types the changes will persist.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can have variable inside your `UITableViewCell` subclass for certain item

```
var item: Item?
```

then in `cellForRowAt` set certain `item` for certain cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ...
    ...
    cell.item = array[indexPath.row]
    ...
}
```

now you can implement `UITextViewDelegate` to your cell subclass and you can use method `textViewDidEndEditing` for handling when user is done with typing

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    ...
    var item: Item?
    ...
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        yourTextView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension YourCell: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
         ... // here save text and here you can use variable `item`
    }
}
```